# Доступ к данным из другого потока

Tags: php, многопоточность

Решил вспомнить PHP и написать простую программу, но столкнулся с проблемой доступа к данным из другого потока, не понимаю что не так, вроде все правильно, но не работает корректно

```
<?php

class B extends Thread {
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function run() {
        var_dump($this->a->method());
    }
}

class A {
    private $socket;
    private $b;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
        if (!$this->socket) {
            echo 'socket create error';
            exit;
        }

        if (!socket_bind($this->socket, '0.0.0.0', 22222)) {
            echo 'socket bind error';
            exit;
        }

        $this->b = new B($this);
        $this->b->start();
        sleep(1);
    }

    public function method() {
        return $this->socket;
    }
}

$a = new A();
```

Выводит:

> int(0)

хотя должно выводится что-то в этом роде:

> resource(4) of type (Socket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось PHP модуль pthreads не поддерживает ресурсы, их нельзя использовать в разных потоках